# Haskell. Problem with WAI simple web app (unpacking bytestrings)

Tags: haskell

Did lot of packing, unpacking and etc playing with Strings and Texts and still stuck,
the goal is simple as hello world with extra request info concatenated:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Network.HTTP.Types (statusOK)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T

application req = do
  return $ responseLBS statusOK [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    $ L.pack $  "Hello World" ++ (unpack $ rawPathInfo req)

main = run 3000 application
```

produces:

```
Couldn't match expected type `GHC.Word.Word8'
           against inferred type `Char'
      Expected type: [GHC.Word.Word8]
      Inferred type: [Char]
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
        `(unpack $ rawPathInfo req)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `"Hello World" ++ (unpack $ rawPathInfo req)
```

Eagerly need hint how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.pack instead of L.pack.

Comment: `import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)`
`import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack)`

looks like complete madness, but it worked!

Comment: Just follow the types: "Hello World" is a String. unpack produces a String. So the argument to L.pack is a `String`. But `L.pack` takes a `[Word]`, which is where the original error came from. L8.pack, on the other hand, takes a `String`, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of packing and unpacking. I don't have wai installed, so I can't test, but something like this should be simpler:

```
application req = do
  return $ responseLBS statusOK [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    $ L.append "Hello World" $ rawPathInfo req
```

i.e. simply use `ByteString`'s `append` rather than `String`'s `(++)`.